# How to "pair" rows together and consolidate them into one when merging two pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Apologies in advance for what will likely be an amalgamation of previous questions/topics.  I've spent a good deal of time on various related articles and believe I'm getting lost in the best approach to use.  The problem is:

I have two Pandas DataFrames of equal dimension, column names, and indices.  They are both derived from separate SQL lookups. I have a third DataFrame which serves as a dict, such that I can use join/merge operations to fill out empty columns in each of the original two DataFrames.  Once that is complete, and the columns in both DataFrames are full, I'd like to stitch them together such that the corresponding entries across the two are combined to one row in one unified DataFrame instead of a row in each DataFrame.  Obviously there will be column naming clash which is part of the problem. Here is a representation:

```
    frame1
Out[87]: 
   matchupid   primary    geo
0      27812  student1   east
1      91876  student3   east
2      65019  student5   west
3      21632  student7  south
frame2
Out[88]: 
   matchupid   primary      geo
0      27812  student2     west
1      91876  student4  central
2      65019  student6    north
3      21632  student8     east
```

Leaving out the control dict to save space in the post, here's what I get when merging each frame to the dictionary frame.  **Results here are correct (to me) so far:**

```
a1 = frame1.merge(dictFrame, on="primary")
a1
Out[70]: 
   matchupid   primary    geo  matchup q1_res q2_res
0      27812  student1   east    27812   fail   41.2
1      91876  student3   east    91876   78.2   pass
2      65019  student5   west    65019  defer    107
3      21632  student7  south    21632  210.4   fail
a2 = frame2.merge(dictFrame, on="primary")
a2
Out[72]: 
   matchupid   primary      geo  matchup q1_res q2_res
0      27812  student2     west    27812  defer   fail
1      91876  student4  central    91876  104.2  defer
2      65019  student6    north    65019   92.2   91.4
3      21632  student8     east    21632   pass   pass
a3 = pd.concat([a1, a2])
a3
Out[75]: 
   matchupid   primary      geo  matchup q1_res q2_res
0      27812  student1     east    27812   fail   41.2
1      91876  student3     east    91876   78.2   pass
2      65019  student5     west    65019  defer    107
3      21632  student7    south    21632  210.4   fail
0      27812  student2     west    27812  defer   fail
1      91876  student4  central    91876  104.2  defer
2      65019  student6    north    65019   92.2   91.4
3      21632  student8     east    21632   pass   pass
```

Now, the desired state would look something like this (a bit contrived since I can't actually figure out how to do it :)).  **THIS IS NOT IMPLEMENTED - THIS IS DESIRED RESULT:**

```
Out[97]: 
   matchupid   primary q1_res q2_res secondary secondary_q1res secondary_q2res
0      27812  student1   fail   41.2      student2        defer         fail
1      91876  student3   78.2   pass      student4        104.2         defer
2      65019  student5  defer    107      student6        92.2          91.4
3      21632  student7  210.4   fail      student8        pass          pass
```

I've tried a few different approaches, and am curious if the fact that both the indices and the matchup IP are the same gives some advantage.  I thought maybe using groupby on the matchupid would let me work in the pairs I need to keep.  The remaining tasks if this worked would be to 1/ turn the two rows into one, 2/ add them to a new(?) DataFrame, and 3/ change the column names.  Would someone mind to suggest an approach or my missing link?  Thanks in advance!

```
grouped = a3.groupby('matchupid')
grouped.get_group(21632)
Out[109]: 
   matchupid   primary q1_res q2_res
3      21632  student7  210.4   fail
3      21632  student8   pass   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a job for `pd.concat(axis=1)`, a "horizontal" concatenation:

```
# Create a temporary DataFrame from a2 with correct column names
temp = a2.rename(columns={'primary': 'secondary', 
                          'q1_res':'secondary_q1res',
                          'q2_res':'secondary_q2res'})
temp = temp.drop(columns=['matchup', 'geo'])

# Horizontally concat with relevant columns of a1
a3 = pd.concat([a1.drop(columns=['matchup', 'geo']), temp], axis=1)
```